# Custom data return in stripe redirect

Tags: php, redirect, stripe-connect, user-data

I want stripe to add some unique data about the user. As it's written in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts), normal URL link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://example.dev/stripe?scope=read_write&code={AUTHORIZATION_CODE}">Connect Stripe</a>
```

And return data will be something like this:

```
array:2 [
  "scope" => "read_write"
  "code" => "{TOKEN_CODE}"
]
```

In my case, because every user owns different domain but redirects back to the same URL I need to know who's who. So can I add data to the redirect link:

```
<a href="http://example.dev/stripe?scope=read_write&code={AUTHORIZATION_CODE}&data={UNIQUE_DATA}">Connect Stripe</a>
```

in order to get this from Stripe server?

```
array:3 [
  "scope" => "read_write"
  "code" => "{TOKEN_CODE}"
  "data" => "{UNIQUE_DATA}"
]
```

Comment: Tried [metadata ?](https://stripe.com/blog/adding-context-with-metadata)

Comment: Please add more substance to your question. I do not understand your question. If you have any code that you're trying to alter it would be best for you to post that information along with your question. Please be detailed as you can.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Can I use metadata in my case? I am not so [sure](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts).

Comment: I believe yes, because you're just going to add few data that the user wants to get redirect, so i guess it should be enough

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, So I am trying this: `<a href="http://example.dev/stripe?scope=read_write&code={AUTHORIZATION_CODE}&metadata[user_url]={UNIQUE_DATA}">Connect Stripe</a>` but server is not returning it. Can you tell me where I am wrong? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually advise to do here is to use a cookie or a session to "remember" your user. Since they come on your website first before being redirected to Stripe you'd be able to save some info in a cookie so that when Stripe redirects them back to your server you know who they are and where they came from to finalize the redirection.

Otherwise, if that doesn't work for you, you could use the `state` parameter when you redirect the user to Stripe and that value would be kept all along and sent back in the URL once the user is redirected to your server. This is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#integrating-oath) where the docs say:

> To prevent CSRF attacks, add the state parameter, passing along a unique token as the value. We’ll include the state you gave us when we redirect the user back to your site.